# Decryption of an unknown cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, decryption

How can I identify the cipher that encrypted the data shown below?

I'm very new to this field, so I am not sure.

For example:

How does one know which cipher is used in the following line? How can one decrypt it?

`` $&Es6a@I+v5;|`h_$)q?2Kq75w=p|%tK+)8K)K}d!b_l ``

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we cannot. Most modern ciphers just output pseudo-random bits or rather bytes. Those can be encoded in any particular way. Otherwise you can try and guess. What you show are seemingly unrelated characters that are still in the ASCII subset, so that may be a hint that it is a classical cipher such as Caesar with an extended character set, to name just one possibility.